# Monitoring SSH Bastion Metrics

Tags: ssh, ssh-tunneling

Given a hardened EC2 instance serving as a bastion (laptops ssh to servers past the bastion via ProxyJump), what are some key metrics to monitor? In particular, I'd like to know if there are any SSH connections that are unstable and how we could remedy on the fly. A few days ago, there were a few SSH connections that kept dropping and/or timing out. We found out via user reports and we ended up simply increasing the instance size, but that doesn't really help us understand *why* these connections were unstable.

Answer (score 0):

You can monitor SSH server performance from your mobile phone

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sonelli.juicessh.performancemonitor&hl=en_US&gl=US